# Preventing base64 conversion of mqtt message payload

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt

Is there a way  I can prevent automatic conversion of mqtt message payload?
When I try to log the messages they convert to string like '0'  converts to \x30
where 1 byte is converted to 4 bytes consuming space.
Here is the code snippet for on_message

```
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    f = msg.topic[1::].replace('/', '-')  + '.log'
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    fh = logging.FileHandler(filename=f)
    fh.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    formatter = logging.Formatter(
                    fmt='%(message)s')
    fh.setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(fh)
    log.info(msg.payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no conversion going on.

MQTT payloads are **always** just byte arrays, if you want to present it as a string you need to decode it with a suitable character encoding (normally UTF-8)

You have already done this once with the `str()` function in  the first line of your function, you just need to do it again in the last line.